# mysql return nested array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, mariadb, inner-join

I have this SQL

```
SELECT
    U.id,
    U.first_name,
    hobby.id,
    hobby.name
FROM
    USER AS U
INNER JOIN user_hobbies AS UH
ON
    UH.user_id = U.id
INNER JOIN hobby ON hobby.id = user_hobbies.hobby_id FOR JSON AUTO
```

am trying to run in in xampp PHP myadmin and am getting an error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON AUTO' at line 11
```

the  `FOR JSON AUTO` is marked red even in SQL input could anyone help on how to so such inner join, return inner array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FOR JSON AUTO` is SQL Server syntax, that is not supported in MySQL. If you are looking to generate one row per user, along with a JSON array of hobbies objects, you can use JSON aggregation like so:

```
select u.id, u.first_name,
    json_arrayagg(json_object('id', h.id, 'name', h.name)) as hobbies
from users u 
inner join user_hobbies uh on h.user_id = u.id
inner join hobbies h on h.id = uh.hobby_id
group by u.id
```

Note that this requires MariaDB 10.5.0 or higher.

Comment: this does not give any error highlight but `FUNCTION  db.json_arrayagg does not exist` on running

Comment: As GMB stated, you need MariaDB 10.5.0 or higher.

Comment: you can eventually simulate that function with: CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('id', h.id, 'name', h.name)),']')

Comment: the latest xampp comes with `10.4.17-MariaDB` so I cannot use it?